# Is $180^\circ = 3.14..$? Correlating the circumference and diameter in terms of degrees

Tags: pi, angle, dimensional-analysis

I'm trying to correlate $\pi$ to the circumference and diameter of a unit circle. Consider a unit circle and represent it in terms of an n-gon. Join each vertex to its center. The angle subtended is $\theta^\circ = \frac{360^\circ}{n}$. Now the base of each of these triangles (formed by the radii and the chord on the arc) is of measure $2\sin\left(\frac{\theta^\circ}{2}\right)$ which can be computed by the cosine rule. The circumference is therefore supposed to be $\displaystyle\lim_{\theta^\circ \to 0^\circ} \left\{n\cdot2\sin\left(\frac{\theta^\circ}{2}\right)\right\} = \displaystyle\lim_{\theta^\circ \to 0^\circ} \left\{\frac{360^\circ}{\theta^{\circ}}\cdot2\sin\left(\frac{\theta^\circ}{2}\right)\right\} = 360^\circ \cdot \displaystyle\lim_{\theta^\circ \to 0^\circ} \left\{\frac{\sin{\left(\frac{\theta^{\circ}}{2}\right)}}{\left(\frac{\theta^{\circ}}{2}\right)}\right\} = 360^{\circ}$

So does $360^{\circ} = 2\pi$? Isn't that supposed to be $2\pi \text{ rad}$ instead of just $2\pi$? We also know that $\pi = 3.14...$ So does $180^\circ = 3.14...$?

Comment: Of course $360^\circ = 2 \pi\ {\rm radians}$.

Comment: If anything, the limit in the last parentheses is $\pi/180°$, which when multiplied with $360°$ gives the correct answer of $2\pi$. Try putting in small numbers for $\theta$.

Comment: In any case the whole notation $\theta°$ is just unfortunate. What we write as $\sin(x°)$ should better be written as something like "$degsin(x)$" ("degree-sin") and is nothing else but $\sin(\frac{\pi}{180}x)$, where $\sin$ is defined e.g. as power series. You can put numbers into a function, not degrees. "Radian measure" is just numbers.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? It should be clear that if $360^{\circ} = 2\pi$ radians then $180^{\circ} = \pi$ radians. If you are asking if $180^{\circ} = \pi$ (as a unitless number) then no, that doesn't make any sense; you have lost track of your units somewhere.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg "You can put numbers into a function, not degrees": what do you mean? You can put anything you want into a function, as long as it is in the domain. For a trig function, I would in fact say "you put angles into the function, not numbers."

Comment: @MorganRodgers: You are right, and yet I think I have a point. What are the "angles, not numbers" you want to put into a trig functions, in particular: How do you compute them? In other words: please write down the exact definition of the sin function, with angles as domain, which allows me to calculate e.g. $\sin(32.7°)$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Exactly the same way as you would define if for an angle in radians. Opposite over hypotenuse sides of a right triangle, relative to an angle of $32.7^{\circ}$. Or the $y$-coordinate of the point on the unit circle corresponding to that angle. I think you are actually confused in thinking "radian measure is just numbers": radians are a type of unit used to measure angles, just like degrees. We can interpret a number as an angle by assuming it is using a particular unit.

Comment: @MorganRodgers: But how do I compute the values of that function? By drawing a big right triangle, with rulers whose precision I trust a lot?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg How would you do it for $0.5707227$ radians (which is the same angle)? The value of a function being defined is not dependent on you knowing an effective way to calculate it.

Comment: @MorganRodgers: Via $x-x^3/6+x^5/120$, and if I feel I need more decimals, I might add two or three more terms. A quick estimate by head gives $\approx 0.54$, and you and I could do that with pen and paper in less than ten minutes to a precision no earthly ruler can measure. Your last sentence is correct, and I misspoke in my earlier comment; yet I feel my viewpoint, which defines $\sin :\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ via the power series, has its merit.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are getting confused is with degree and radians. Now, as we know angles can be expressed in degree as well as radians. When in any equations we use angles in degree what we get is degree related value. Whereas radians outputs only number. There is no unit to attach with the answer. Lets take an example:-

$f(x) = \frac {\sin x}{x}$ , for $x \in \mathbb R$ thereby $f(x)\in\mathbb R$

Now if we take $x = 30^\circ $.
The answer is $f(30^\circ)=0.0167\ degree^-1$

Now if we take $x=30\ radians\ or\ only\ 30$.
The answer is $f(30)=-0.988$
The reason behind it is we assume radians as unit less, calculations using radians give pure numbers. But with degree we have to associate it with the answer. Another prominent Example would be Angular Velocity.
$V = \dot \theta = \frac{d\theta}{dt} $
If we used $degrees\ as\ unit\ of\ \theta,\ then\ the\ unit\ of\ V\ is\ degree.s^-1, But\ if\ radians\ is\ used\ then\ radians.s^-1\ or \ simply\ s^-1    $
And also the radians is defined as:
$1\ radians$ is defined as the angles subtended by an arc such that the arc length is same as the radius.
As we can see its a ratio, an unit less substance.